# How to get all servers' names where my discord bot in JDA

Tags: java, discord-jda

I'm setting up a SQLite to my Discord bot and I want to create a db file to every server with servers' name but I can't find the Guild to each server

I have a class to create the connection to sql and the main, the method to create a connection works good but I just need to create for each server a db file

This is my SQLite connection class:

```java
    package LiteSQL;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.sql.*;

    public class LiteSQL {

    private static Connection con;
    private static Statement stmt;
    public static void connect(String serverName){
        con=null;

        try{

            File file = new File(serverName+".db");
            if(!file.exists())
                file.createNewFile();

            String url="jdbc:sqlite:"+file.getPath();
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            stmt = con.createStatement();

            System.out.println("SQL Connected");
        }catch(SQLException | IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }



    public static void disconnect(){
        try{
            if(con!=null) {
                con.close();
                System.out.println("Disconnected from SQL");
            }
        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void onUpdate(String sql){
        try{

            stmt.execute(sql);
        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static ResultSet onQury(String sql){
        try{
            return stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
        }
    }
```

and this is my Main method

```java
    package Main;

    import Commands.*;
    import Commands.AdminCommands.Clear;
    import Commands.AdminCommands.Verify;
    import Commands.AdminCommands.mute;
    import Commands.AdminCommands.unmute;
    import Commands.Music.*;
    import Events.MemberJoin;
    import Events.MemberLeave;
    import Events.Reactions;
    import LiteSQL.LiteSQL;
    import net.dv8tion.jda.core.AccountType;
    import net.dv8tion.jda.core.JDA;
    import net.dv8tion.jda.core.JDABuilder;
    import net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.Game;
    import net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.Guild;

    public class Bot {

    public static final String prefix = "~";
    public static JDA jda;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        LiteSQL.connect(I need to put here the servers' names);
         jda = new 
     JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT).setToken("NTkzMDgwMjIyMDMxNTQ0MzIx.XRI0wA.2TKzqfhrimbdip684e30QfFhMK8").build();


        jda.getPresence().setGame(Game.playing("Java Version bot '~'     prefix"));


        }


    }
```

In the line `LiteSQL.connect(I need to put here the servers' names);`
I need to put every server name where my bot is connected to

Comment: Congratulations on leaking your login token. Now go ahead and regenerate it.

Comment: already did it dont worry thx

Answer (score 0):

You cannot request a list of servers from the JDA before you build it.
To ensure that the JDA has loaded properly you could try to connect to the database after  the JDA fires the ReadyEvent.

To get an ArrayList containing all guilds names the bot is connected to, request the JDA from the ReadyEvent:

```
private List<String> getGuilds(ReadyEvent event) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Guild guild : event.getJDA().getGuilds())
        list.add(guild.getName());
    return list;
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't even compile. You are setting your return type to `ArrayList<>` but you return `List<String>`. Better would be doing `getGuildCache().applyStream(guilds -> guilds.map(Guild::getName).collect(Collectors.toList()))` and returning that.